# XHTML img shrinked in tables only on ereader

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have this basic XHTML file, with a table that displays images in the first column (images size is roughly 64x64 pix) and some text in the second column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
  <link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../Images/A.png"/></td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sapien tortor, malesuada convallis mi quis, mattis porta eros. Integer sed massa et felis aliquam interdum eget sed massa. Vestibulum luctus, lacus in posuere consectetur, neque orci maximus lectus, tristique aliquam tortor nulla id lacus. Sed tempor auctor felis at vulputate. Duis euismod, metus sed hendrerit blandit, sem tortor laoreet lorem, non feugiat quam nunc condimentum erat. Vestibulum sit amet laoreet est, vel sollicitudin urna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque sodales tincidunt turpis eget sollicitudin. Nunc et tincidunt ligula, at tristique orci. Praesent ut congue mauris. Praesent non metus ut libero sagittis hendrerit et ac dui. Donec eget ultricies risus, quis euismod massa.</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../Images/D.png"/></td>
        <td><p>Donec pretium dapibus felis at vestibulum. Morbi posuere mauris ac facilisis sollicitudin. Praesent iaculis mauris molestie ante cursus, sit amet ornare velit viverra. Cras dictum sollicitudin erat, mollis tempus orci hendrerit sit amet. Mauris orci nunc, sodales ut metus sit amet, pretium posuere velit. Mauris elementum, dolor ut laoreet faucibus, neque purus fringilla urna, vel tristique lacus odio sit amet purus. Suspendisse eget ultricies libero. Sed a semper augue. Morbi ac ligula ut nibh ornare eleifend nec ut nisl. Quisque ut rhoncus odio. </p></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening the file in a browser, images in the first column are displayed full size. If I shrink the window, or force tablet/smartphone view in the browser, images are still displayed full size.

I added the file to an epub. Opening it with an ebook reader (Calibre default one) I see everything like in the browser (i.e. full size images).

I've uploaded the epub on my erader device (an old Kobo Touch). Here images are shrinked to a very small size.

Why is this happening?

Could it be an ereader problem? Likely. Any HTML/css trick to force full size?

I've tried to add this to the css file

```
table img {
  height: 100%! important;
}
```

Still no luck, the images are shrinked.

Comment: I have no experience with e-readers, but have you tried a meta viewport instruction?

Comment: Well, I don't have that much experience with html and css, instead. Can you further explain you idea?

Comment: I mean, try putting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>` in the head. This tells the browser to not try tricks like resizing to make the page more visible, at least on phones and tablets. (Like I said, no experience with Ereaders.)

Comment: By the way, are you sure it's real XHTML? There is a well-formedness error in your source, which would prevent browsers from showing anything if it was real XHTML.

Comment: I'll try the meta viewpoint snippet. Also, I've corrected the code snippet.

Comment: The meta didn't help, awfully. Same behavior.